# Search all classes in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, search, find

Is there a search function to search for a particular string across all classes in a project in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: FYI: `CTRL+Shift+L` shows a list with all the available shortcuts to use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm

Ctrl Shift G

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+SHIFT+G goes perfect for searching similar string in project

Comment: Maybe, but what does this add to the accepted 20112 answer?